# Can a set of functional dependencies contain an attribute not in the relation?

Tags: database, relation, functional-dependencies

Example: Consider the relation `R = (A,B,C)` and the set of FDs, `F = (AB -> C, C -> D)`.

Notice D is not in the relation R, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, functional dependencies are defined on sets of the relation attributes.